# rolify (n+1) issue using with_role

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails facing the issue of n+1 problem.

Controller:

```
def index
    @merchants = Merchant.includes(users: [:users_roles])
    .page(params[:page]).per(10)
end
```

View:

```
<% @merchants.each do |m| %>
<% admins = m.users.with_role('merchant') %>
```

It is fetching 10 queries while listing.

Comment: I hope this helps : [N+1 Query Problem](https://www.sitepoint.com/silver-bullet-n1-problem/)

Comment: Try this http://deepakmahakale.github.io/blog/2016/06/16/include-scoped-associations.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you have included user roles which will avoid `n + 1 queries` if you fire

```
@merchant.first.users
# or
@merchant.first.users.first.user_roles
```

but

```
admins = m.users.with_role('merchant')
```

the code above adds a where condition which will not use the included associations.

**Solution**

Create a new association in merchant with condition something like

```
has_many :merchant_users, -> { joins(:user_roles).where(user_roles: { name: 'merchant' }) }, class_name: 'User'
```

and include it

```
@merchants = Merchant.includes(merchant_users: [:users_roles])
```

Refer this post about how to [include-scoped-associations](http://deepakmahakale.github.io/blog/2016/06/16/include-scoped-associations.html)